# Non-uniqueness of an Ultrafilter on a set.

Tags: general-topology

If an Ultrafilter $\mathcal A$ on $X$ is the maximal Filter on that set, then how can there be more than one Ultrafilter on any given set? If $U_1, U_2$ - Ultrafilters, then $U_1 \subset U_2$, since $U_1$ is a Filter and $U_2$ an Ultrafilter as well as $U_2 \subset U_1$, since $U_2$ is a Filter and $U_1$ an Ultrafilter. So $U_1 = U_2$. Where is my mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Maxim**al*** does not imply *maxim**um***. The family of filters on $A$ is partially ordered by $\subseteq$, not linearly ordered, and it has many maximal elements with respect to that order: there is no maxim**um** ultrafilter on $A$ (assuming that $|A|\ge 2$).

This is especially clear if we look at principal ultrafilters on $A$. Let $a,b\in A$ with $a\ne b$. Let $\mathscr{U}_a=\{U\subseteq A:a\in U\}$, the principal ultrafilter over $a$, and $\mathscr{U}_b=\{U\subseteq A:b\in U\}$, the principal ultrafilter over $b$; then $\mathscr{U}_a$ and $\mathscr{U}_b$ are ultrafilters on $A$, $\{a\}\in\mathscr{U}_a\setminus\mathscr{U}_b$, and $\{b\}\in\mathscr{U}_b\setminus\mathscr{U}_a$, so $\mathscr{U}_a\nsubseteq\mathscr{U}_b$, and $\mathscr{U}_b\nsubseteq\mathscr{U}_a$. Both are maximal, and neither is a subset of the other.

(To check that $\mathscr{U}_a$, for instance, is maximal, let $S\subseteq A$. If $S\notin\mathscr{U}_a$, then $a\notin S$, so $a\in A\setminus S$, $A\setminus S\in\mathscr{U}_a$, and $\mathscr{U}_a\cup\{S\}$ is not a proper filter, since $S\cap(A\setminus S)=\varnothing$.)